# "we are going to deal with that which belongs to geometry” - correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is it correct to use the word "**which**" directly after "**that**"?

This is the context:

> "There are many meanings to the word “axis”, but we are going to deal
>   with **that which** belongs to geometry”

Comment: Yes, this sounds idiomatic and slightly formal.

Comment: Why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: A relevant [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+that+which+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwith%20that%20which%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20they%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20had%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20that%20which%20it%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's grammatically correct because "that"refers to the "meaning " though I believe "the one belonging to" might be better.